# Need help displaying output for Golf Game

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I need some help, I don't know how I would display the players and the hole that they won in this program.

```
    Public Class GolfGame
    Private Sub btnPlay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click
        Dim array(3, 8) As Integer
        Dim intLow As Integer = 0
        Scores.Items.Add(vbTab & "Hole 1" & vbTab & "Hole 2" & vbTab & "Hole 3" & vbTab & "Hole 4" & vbTab & "Hole 5" & vbTab & "Hole 6" & vbTab & "Hole 7" & vbTab & "Hole 8" & vbTab & "Hole 9")
        Randomize()
        For outer = 0 To 3
            For inner As Integer = 0 To 8
                array(outer, inner) = Int((8 * Rnd()) + 1)
            Next
            Scores.Items.Add("Player " & outer + 1 & vbTab & array(outer, 0) & vbTab & array(outer, 1) & vbTab & array(outer, 2) & vbTab & array(outer, 3) & vbTab & array(outer, 4) & vbTab & array(outer, 5) & vbTab & array(outer, 6) & vbTab & array(outer, 7) & vbTab & array(outer, 8))
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To 8
            For j As Integer = 0 To 3
                If array(j, i) < intLow Then
                    intLow = array(j, i)
                    If j = 0 And i = 0 Then
                        P1.Text = "Player 1 has won this hole."
                    ElseIf j = 1 And i = 0 Then
                        P2.Text = "Player 2 has won this hole."
                    ElseIf j = 2 And i = 0 Then
                        P3.Text = "Player 3 has won this hole"
                    ElseIf j = 3 And i = 0 Then
                        P4.Text = "Player 4 has won this hole."
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            intLow = 9
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The If statement does not seem to be working within the loop. Any ideas to tackle this? Should the output just be one big if statement, or is there something simpler that I am just missing?

Comment: Please remove the line numbers to increase readability of the code.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: Which "if statement" is not working? If it the "If array(j,i)" one, then I would check that array(j,i) or intlow isn't nothing. if it the others, then you definitely will want to change to a select case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just learning, so I'll try to help you out.

First of all, you don't say how `Scores` and `P1` through `P4` are defined. It looks like `Scores` might be a List(Of String) and `P1` through `P4` are text boxes or labels of some sort. I'll make those assumptions for now. You begin by sending output to `Scores`, but then you use the text boxes instead. You need to settle on how you're going to display your output and go with one option.

You begin by assigning a random integer from 1 to 8 for each player/hole combination. That part looks OK.

Then you've attempted to write an algorithm to determine which player won each hole. What you've written is very confused and won't work. There are multiple problems.

- `intLow` is 0 when you attempt to find the winner of the first hole. Then you set it to 9 for holes 2 through 9 (outer 1 through 8). That can't work. You need to be consistent.
- When `intLow` is 0, your main `If` statement:

  `If array(j, i) < intLow Then`

  ...will always fail, because the values you've stored in Scores will never be less than zero.
- On subsequent iterations, your main `If` statement will always succeed because `intLow` has been set to 9 and the maximum score is 8. However, by this time, `i` will not be 0 and all your inner `If` statements will fail.
- `intLow` contains the wrong information. You want to store the player who won the hole, not what the low score was. If `intLow` contains the index of the player who won the hole, then you can easily get the score.

So your program essentially does nothing. You need to adjust the algorithm to properly determine which player won a hole. This would do it:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 8
   intLow = 0
   For j As Integer = 1 To 3
      If array(j, i) < array(intLow, i) Then
         intLow = j
      End If
   Next j
   ' At this point, you know that player intLow+1 won hole i+1 with a score of
   ' array(intLow, i). Ties always go to the first player who made that score.
Next i
```

In this revision, notice that we compare players to one another rather than to a constant value like 9. When determining the minimum or maximum in a list, this is a better practice. Granted, the scoring range for a hole of golf is always 1 - 8, but most minimums and maximums tend to have a way of changing over time. You want your algorithm to work no matter what.

I'll leave the output part up to you. This looks like an assignment and I've probably given too much away already.

Other suggestions:

- `Scores` is a poorly named variable. It contains output, so `Output` might be a better name.
- `array` is not descriptive. It contains scores. Once `Scores` is renamed, a good name for `array` would be `Scores`.
- `i` could be called `hole` and `j` could be called `player`. That would help you keep things straight.
- `intLow` could be called `winner`, which implies that the variable contains the index of the winner. `intLow` could mean low score or player with the lowest score. This ambiguity might have confused you. It definitely confused me.
- There are native .Net methods for truncating the decimal portion of a number and for generating random numbers. There are even ways to generate random integers directly. You are using a legacy way of doing it, which VB.net provides for backward compatibility with VB6. That's 1990s technology. Programmers unfamiliar with VB6 will look at your code will find this very confusing, which is why it's generally better to use the native features of the .Net framework.